# VLookup Macro for Changing Column Reference

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create macro for vlookup, but in my case the column reference automatically change from 1 criteria to the next. The problem is as following:

In one excel sheet I have list of all companies & the available products.

http://wikisend.com/download/910578/product.jpg

Now I've a sheet for each company. I want to vlookup for each company & put the available products in the particular company sheet. The new sheet will look like this.

[http://wikisend.com/download/482612/single comp.png](http://wikisend.com/download/482612/single%20comp.png)

I cannot just copy & insert columns as in each companies column there are already name of products. Also, I want the macro to do it for all the companies (each company has a seperate sheet as X1).

Thank you for your help.

Updated Code:

```
Sub UpProd()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim DataRange As Range, UpdateRange As Range, aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    Dim s As String
    Dim z As Variant
    s = "X1,X2,X3"
    z = VBA.Split(s, ",")
    On Error GoTo Err

    For Each i In z
        Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet5")
        Set UpdateRange = Worksheets(i).Range("A2:A21")
        Set DataRange = ws.Range("A2:A12")
        For Each aCell In UpdateRange
            Set bCell = DataRange.Find(What:=aCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

           If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                aCell.Offset(, 1) = bCell.Offset(, 1)
            End If
        Next
    Next i
    Exit Sub
Err:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: imgur is down at the moment. Can you upload the images in wikisend.com and share the link here?

Comment: Hi Siddharth, I've put the wikisend in my post itself. Thanks

Comment: So If I understand correctly, you have sheets like X1, X2... And you want to update the values from Product Sheet?

Comment: yes. In 2nd screenshot, I gave the example of how X1, X2 sheet looks like.

Comment: In that case See `Section 4` in this link http://siddharthrout.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/ Give it a try and if you get stuck post the code that you tried and we will take it form there. :)

Comment: Hi Siddharth, This code works fine, when I'm using it for Sheet "X1". But it doesnot go to the next sheet, i.e. "X2". When going to Sheet "X2", it showing error "object Variable Or With Block Variable not set". This maybe because the "Offset(, 1)" reference. Also, here I've to manually fix the range, for both DataRange & UpdateRange. I guess this is the best I could do so far. I put the code in my question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good initiative to try and solve the problem :). You are very close! You have to in fact loop through all sheets and then use 2 `.Finds`. One for the Company Name and the other for Products.

See this code (**TRIED AND TESTED**)

Please ensure that you take a moment to read the comments that I put.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim wsP As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range

    '~~> Replace below with the name of the sheet which has the products
    Set wsP = Sheets("Product")

    '~~> Loop through every sheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        '~~> Ensure that we ignore the product sheet
        If ws.Name <> wsP.Name Then
            With ws
                '~~> Get the last row of Col A in ws
                lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

                '~~> Check the rows in product sheet to find which column
                '~~> has the Company name I am assuming that the company
                '~~> names are in row 1 unlike row 2 in your screenshot
                '~~> If it is actually 2 then change Rows(1) to Rows(2)
                Set aCell = wsP.Rows(1).Find(What:=ws.Name, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

                '~~> Check if company name is found
                If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                    For i = 2 To lRow

                        '~~> Check Column 1 to find the product
                        Set bCell = wsP.Columns(1).Find(What:=ws.Range("A" & i).Value, _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

                        '~~> If found then pick up the value from the relevant column
                        If Not bCell Is Nothing Then _
                        ws.Range("B" & i).Value = wsP.Cells(bCell.Row, aCell.Column).Value

                    Next i
                Else
                    MsgBox "Company Name not found. Moving on to the next sheet"
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next ws

    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: It worked perfectly fine. I was cracking my head for past week to solve this problem. Thank you for great help!

Comment: I had the code ready but was waiting for you to show some efforts which you did ;) So basically all thanks to you :)